# Unable To add dependencies in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to add Library in android studio using build.gradle file

Here is my **build.gradle(Module)** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.akshay.popupdemo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.7"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7'
}
```

and my **build.gradle(project)** file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
```

I Got The Following Error

```
   D:\Yogesh_Kadam_Projects\Android-Projects\Current Projects\PopUpDemo\app\build.gradle
    Error:Error:line (36)Failed to resolve: com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.3
    Error:Error:line (37)Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
    Error:Error:line (38)Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.7
```

I know how to add using library Folder and then adding dependencies using project structure  dialog box.

How to add library using build.gradle file ?

What Setting should i made into android studio to download library by its own?
Please Explain.

[**Log IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j458S.png)

Comment: Provide full errorlog

Comment: It's odd. I guess that offline works is enabled. Check `Preferences > Build, Exceution, Deployment > Gradle > offline work` is unchecked.

Comment: @nshmura offline work is already disabled

Comment: Mmm... this may be connection issue like network connection or proxy settings.

Comment: @nshmura proxy work fine

Comment: mmm.. you can update AndroidStudio to 2.2.1 and update gradle android-gradle-plugin to latest version. but this will not solve problems..

Answer (score 0):

@yogesh

try to add dependencies using Module Setting -> Dependencies -> Library Dependency

paste dependency path on search area 
for ex. com.google.code.gson:gson and this will search & rectify the dependency with proper version